# Personal access token is not writeable in terminal of vs code? What to do

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

When i run git push -u origin master
I got authentication concerns, there 3 options of web,device code,personal access token.
I generated fine-grained personal access token for first push.
I copied the token.
But it is not type-able in the VS code terminal. What is going on.

I tried shortcut keys, these did not worked.
I was trying to write Personel Acess Token or pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when a console program designed for Unix (like Git) wants to prompt for a password, it simply turns off the echo for the terminal.  This means that you can type or paste things, but nothing appears on the screen until after you hit Enter.

In many GUI programs, you'll see stars or bullet points instead, but you won't see that here, so just paste or type as normal, and then hit Enter, and it will be accepted even though nothing appears on the screen.

The reason for this is that older terminals didn't offer the ability to echo stars, and as a consequence, this is the simplest and most portable approach that works across systems.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where I couldn't paste my "Token" into the terminal window in VS code,
However, I tried one way:

***copy token > right click*** and it will be automatically pasted